# trying open blender but getting error failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead.and crashing. what to do?

Tags: windows

I am new to blender and installed it for the first time in my computer.

And when i started it  showed a error "Error AL lib: UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead.". And the error closed automatically and blender did not open at all.

I looked around on internet and found the most common solution to this problem was deleting the config files in appdata. But the thing is there is no Blender Foundation folder in my appdata\Roaming

What should i do?. My blender is 2.79

Comment: No in that question the error after the program opened. And for him it did not crash. But for me the program did not even open.

Comment: It is likely that the crash is not related to the error you see (many people get that message) but something entirely different that remains unreported, ie. you are really getting a silent crash.

Comment: I get that error constantly, blender works fine with it